# How to correct egg nog that is too sweet?

Tags: drinks

I have a large carton of Producers “All-Natural” Egg Nog. The actual taste itself is only slightly too sweet but the main issue is that it leaves a SUPER sweet after-taste that tastes like flavored lip gloss. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

1) Too sweet, you could dilute it with some rum or other alcohol. That might mask the sweet aftertaste with an alcoholic aftertaste....

2) Grate some nutmeg on top: fresh nutmeg has such a bite, your tastebuds will forget about the sweetness.

3) While you're at it you could further dilute it with a little half and half, or just plain milk.

Answer (score 1):

Eggnog is primarily made using egg yolks, cream, milk, spices, and a sweetener. If it's too sweet, you can mix in heavy whipping cream and/or any kind of milk to dilute it. As often done in traditional eggnogs, you could beat egg whites until foamy and stir that in. It'll add a frothier texture and more volume to the drink so that it's not as sweet. You could also add more spices and flavorings to mask the sweetness, such as nutmeg, cinnamon, or vanilla extract.